# Babel.config.js plugins are being ignored, expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I have been trying to install a plugin in my babel.config.js. The problem is that the plugins are being ignore entirely. I am using a expo dev client so maybe it could be related to that? I have cleared my cache multiple times, so that is not the issue. Any and all help would be appreciated, I have been trying to fix this issue for multiple days now and I none of the solutions ive found have worked. Thanks in advance.

My babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  
  return {
    
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      [
        'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
        {
          globals: ['__scanCodes'],
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

The error im getting:

`ReferenceError: Property '__scanOCR' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes`

I have tried reformating my babel.config.js and clearing the cache but it has not worked.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I am trying to run local bare workflow builds from an expo project, and I think my babel.config.js is being completely ignored. Console.logs or even errors thrown inside the file do nothing

Comment: have you figured this one out? thanks!

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the config and error, you made `__scanCodes` a global variable via your config,

```js
{
   globals: ['__scanCodes'],
}
```

but seems you're calling `__scanOCR` instead of `__scanCodes` somewhere else in your code